# SPARK : WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: ssh, apache-spark, bigdata, scheduling, spark-streaming

So I was trying to install Apache Spark 1.2.1 Standalone cluster on ubuntu from the following link.
[How to install](https://trongkhoanguyenblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/how-to-install-spark-1-1-on-ubuntu/)

But instead of cloning the slave from the master in VmWare Workstation I used two different machines.

I have declared following variables in spark-env.sh

```
# - SPARK_MASTER_IP, to bind the master to a different IP address or hostname
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=<master-node IP>
# - SPARK_MASTER_PORT / SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the master
# - SPARK_MASTER_OPTS, to set config properties only for the master (e.g. "-Dx=y")
# - SPARK_WORKER_CORES, to set the number of cores to use on this machine
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
# - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY, to set how much total memory workers have to give executors (e.g. 1000m, 2g)
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=200m
# - SPARK_WORKER_PORT / SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT, to use non-default ports for the worker
# - SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES, to set the number of worker processes per node
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
```

Now when I run the following command

```
./sbin/start-all.sh
```

Though on the slave machine, 2 java processes come up in the system monitor but the Master Node system's UI does not show any worker node.

Still moving on when I run the command

```
MASTER=spark://<master node ip>:7077 ./bin/spark-shell
```

following error comes up

```
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

I have ensured to put the correct IP of the system whenever required and also tried decreasing the memory allotted to worker nodes..but still the problem persists.

Kindly help.

Also any guidance/references[except the spark programming guide] for doing streaming in spark will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring due to insufficient memory with the worker nodes.

Following two solutions are possible :

- Try to allocate more memory to worker virtual machines.
- Decrease the memory allocated to worker nodes in   "spark-env.sh"
  file.

Comment: The error was caused from the RAM limitation of my system(4GB) due to which I was able to allot less than 1GB to my worker nodes.